# Is "Opening by the Host" understandable?

Tags: word-request

I am writing the itinerary of a conference. At the start, a host comes, says hi and describes what will happen during the day. How can I refer to this? Is "Opening by the Host" a good choice?

By the way, by *host* I do not mean the chairman. I mean someone like a showman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP refers to Master of Ceremonies (emcee).

I think you can use:

"Introduction - Schedule of Activities (Emcee)"

Note: the choice of words is up to you, same goes for the format.

Comment: It is a scientific conference. Is emcee the best choice?

Comment: I'd use Master of Ceremonies.

Answer (score 1):

"Opening remarks by ________________, Conference Host [Chair?]" would be better.

As you can see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opening), when "opening" is used as a noun it usually means a physical hole/aperture or the beginning of a game (most commonly, chess).

Comment: by host I do not mean the chairman. I mean someone like a showman. Edited my Q.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like it might simply be a "Welcome," or an "Introduction" . . . .

Answer (score 1):

I would leave out the word "host" altogether, and simply entitle this as:

> Opening Remarks

An alternative would be:

> Conference Welcome and Announcements

Answer (score 0):

A distinct noun can give a slight advantage in terms of understandability.  For instance you can call it

> Agenda ***presentation***.

since it is given by a professional presenter.  You could call him "MC" if you wish ("Master of Ceremonies").

Comment: by host I do not mean the chairman. I mean someone like a showman.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question so I could justify editing my answer.

Comment: I edited my question.